# How to add a new item to a MutableLiveData MutableList? (Android - Kotlin)

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelist

I have a variable:

`private var a = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Int>>()`

Variable that I want to assign a value to when the button is clicked.

For example for every click, add a new random int to the list, like:
[] -> [5] -> [5,7] -> [5,7,3] -> // etc

How can I add an item to a MutableList of Int that is wrapped in LiveData and empty as default?

I know that in order to add a value in MutableList i should use `a.value.add()`
but this case i have to first use `a.setValue()`
cause variabe a is MutableLiveData.
I can't get it, how i should combine this methods. Or is there another better solution?

I searched a lot, but not found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `LiveData` stores a single value, and *pushes* updates to observers. When something `observe`s it, that `Observer` will be called if the `LiveData` currently has a value. Then, whenever that value changes, every registered observer will be called again with the new value.

To actually *change* that stored value, you need a `MutableLiveData` - this has the `setValue` (and similar) functions that allow you to update it. A plain `LiveData` (which `MutableLiveData` is a subclass of) doesn't allow you to change the value.

Generally you're recommended to do this kind of thing, e.g. in your `ViewModel`:

```
private val _myLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>("hi")
val myLiveData: LiveData = _myLiveData
// or 'val myLiveData: LiveData get() = _myLiveData' which doesn't create a new backing field
```

So internally you hold this `_myLiveData` which is mutable, and private to the `ViewModel`. That allows you to call `setValue` on it, etc. But you also expose it publicly as `myLiveData` which is a **non-mutable** `LiveData` type. This means that any external consumers can't call `setValue` on it, because a `LiveData` doesn't have those.

You're basically not telling consumers that it's actually a `MutableLiveData`, just that it's a `LiveData` in general. That keeps things cleaner, because they can't mess with it without making an effort to do so (e.g. casting it to `MutableLiveData`). This way, only the owner of the data can set the value on it - everything else only **reacts** to changes. Anything that needs to update that value needs to go through the `ViewModel`, e.g. through a function. This lets the `ViewModel` control the data, and how and when it gets changed.

---

Hopefully that makes the difference between `LiveData` and `MutableLiveData` clearer - they're sort of two ways of looking at the same thing, it's just one is meant for the owner of the data (it needs to be able to update/mutate the stored value, that's the whole point!) and one is meant for consumers (they get a read-only view).

So to update the value, and push it to observers, you **have to have a `MutableLiveData` and you **have to call `setValue()` on it** (or `postValue` if you need to). This is especially important when your `LiveData` holds a list, because mutating that list by changing its contents **won't push an update to observers**. As far as the `LiveData` is concerned, it's still holding the same value (a specific list object) and it has no idea if that's been changed. You have to explicitly update the value on the `LiveData`.

---

So you have two options. One is you can update your list with `add` or whatever, and then call `setValue` *with the same list object*. That will push an update, because you've *"changed the value"* - this is true even if you haven't updated the list at all, you're just forcing an update to the `LiveData`.

But that can cause problems, because the last value your observers got was *the same list object*. If you mutate it by changing the contents, everything that's storing that list as *"the previous data"* will see that change, because they're looking at the same list object. If you push that *"new"* data with `setValue`, observers will get the same list object they got last time. And if they need to compare them, they'll see they're exactly the same and *"no change has happened"*, because they're comparing the same list object to itself.

*So it's usually a better idea* to push a **new** list instead, so you're not interfering with the previous data. Meaning you should avoid using `MutableList` completely, and do this kind of thing instead:

```
private val _numbers = MutableLiveData<List<Int>>()
val numbers: LiveData = _numbers

// when updating
val newNumbers = (_numbers.value ?: emptyList()).plus(newNumber)
_numbers.setValue(newNumbers)

// or in a more Kotliny way
_numbers.value = (_numbers.value ?: emptyList()) + newNumber
```

Or if you're happy to have an empty list as your initial `LiveData` value (the above only provides observers with a list that has *at least one Int in it*):

```
// now the LD contains a list as a default value
private val _numbers = MutableLiveData<List<Int>>(emptyList())
val numbers: LiveData = _numbers

// updating - since we know the LD always contains a list, it can't be null
_numbers.value = _numbers.value!! + newNumber
```

So you're using [`plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) to create a *new list* which is everything in the old one *plus* the new value. That way, the old list doesn't change, and anything that's hanging onto it won't get the data mysteriously changing behind its back.

Answer (score 0):

Your code there is triply mutable (`var`, *Mutable*LiveData, *Mutable*List), which is very error prone. You have a `var` so you could write code that swaps out your MutableLiveData for a different instance, which would cause observers to never get updates. You have a MutableList, so if it's modified, observers won't be automatically notified. And even if you do force a change using `value = value.apply { add(someNumber) }`, it will break when used with Compose or ListAdapter, or other classes that want to compare old and new values.

The safe way to do it is to choose only one source of mutability, the MutableLiveData:

```
private val a = MutableLiveData<List<Int>>()
```

When you want to add an item to it, set the value to a new list, for example:

```
fun addItemToA(item: Int) {
    a.value = a.value + item // creates a new List and assigns it to LiveData value
}
```

or more simply:

```
fun addItemToA(item: Int) {
    a.value += item
}
```